# How to download file to Ansible Controller instead to Remote Machine?

Tags: ansible

I'm having two machines. One is the Ansible Controller where I execute my playbooks from and the other one is the Remote Machine (`target`) which I would like to install/update. The important thing is that the Controller runs within the corporate network but the `target` is outside that network (only accessible via ssh).

So I need to download a file (from within the corporate network) and copy it to the `target` node.

I've tried to use: `ansible.builtin.get_url` to download the file but unfortunately it will do that on the Remote (`target`) Machine which has of course no access to the corporate network.

Does someone has a tip/idea?

Update: Using ansible [core 2.11.6]

Comment: If you use `get_url` with `delegate_to: localhost` it will not leave the Ansible Controller node.

Comment: I've already read and tried `delegate_to` which results to: `{"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (ansible.builtin.get_url) module: delegate_to.`...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To download something to the local Ansible Controller you may use the following approach.

```yaml
- name: Download something to Ansible Controller
  delegate_to: localhost
  get_url:
    url: "https://{{ ansible_user }}:{{ ansible_password }}@files.example.com/installer.rpm"
    dest: "/tmp/{{ ansible_user }}"
    owner: "{{ ansible_user }}"
  tags: download,local
```

Please take note that according [Controlling where tasks run: delegation and local actions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html), `delegate_to` is not a parameter of module `get_url` but of the task.

Comment: The hint about not being a parameter of `get_url` was the trick. Oh my gosh.. Thanks.

Comment: Don't worry, I've ran into similar issues quite often in the past.